# Determine whether $b$ is in col$(A)$ and whether $w$ is in row$(A$)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Okay, so I have given this problem A shot. I got the answer so col$(A)$ however, I was just wondering if I did it correctly? Here is my work:

$$
A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & -3 \\
        0 & 2 & 1 \\
        1 & -1 & -4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$
b=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I made an augmented matrix and reduced it all the way down to

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&0&-7/2&1/2\\
      0&1&1/2&1/2\\
      0&0&0&0
    \end{array}
\right] $$

From this I made equations. I let

$x_3= t$.

I solved and got

$x2= 1/2 - 1/(2t)$

$x_1= 1/2 + 7/2(t)$

So, in the equation $Ax=b$. I got that

$$
X=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1/2 + 7/2(t) \\
        1/2 - 1/2(t) \\
        t\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

And so, $b$ is in col$(A)$. Is this the correct way to solve this? I also, had another question. Now, I need to find out whether $w$ is in row$(A)$.

$$
w=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 4 & -5 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I once again made it into an augmented matrix (except its a row... sorry I have no idea how to make that kind of matrix on here). I reduced it down but now I'm stuck and I think it is mainly because I'm not used to an augmented matrix looking like this. Anyway, this is what I get. The line is between row 3 and row 4.

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -7/2 \\
        0 & 1 & 1/2 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this way is easier and more general:

To find the column space of a matrix, you don't need to use an augmented matrix.  Just use column reduction, which will get you to: $$\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1&1&-3\\
      0&2&1\\
      1&-1&-4
    \end{array}
\right] \sim
\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1&0&0\\
      0&2&1\\
      1&-2&-1
    \end{array}
\right] \sim \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1&0&0\\
      0&1&0\\
      1&-1&0
    \end{array}
\right]$$
Then your column space is just the span of the nonzero column vectors.  So: $$\text{span} \left(\begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        -1\\
        \end{bmatrix}\right)$$
Then to check if $b$ is in this span, just see if it can be represented as a linear combination of these 2 vectors.  In this case $b = 1\begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix} +  1\begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        -1\\
        \end{bmatrix}$.

To find the row space, use row reduction instead of column reduction and then the nonzero rows will span your row space.